# Location of sql file for codeigniter application

Tags: sql, codeigniter

I am moving a codeigniter application from one hosting company to another one. Previous hosting company has provided a zip file. In which folder will I find database file (sql)? Application uses MySql. 
I don't find any sql file in the application folder or its childern folders.

Comment: you need to export it from phpmyadmin from your c panel

Comment: Anshu, Sorry, I want to know which folder contains database file. Each codeigniter app has folders like Application, System etc. Does the database file reside in the parent directory which has Application, System etc Or does it go under Application or what?